# how to pass ip address into kvm (identify KVM)?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I would like to identify each KVM instance as it is started up, and one of the ways that i figured i can do this is pass IP address into the KVM in the command line arguments. However, i can't seem to do that for some reason. I used the following command:

```
kvm -smp 1 -vnc :3 -net net=10.0.2.2 -daemonize -drive file="master.qcow2" "$@"
```

Where it gives me an error:

```
No type specified for -net
```

Anyone have any solution for this problem or the more general problem of identifying kvm instances?

thanks a lot!

Jason

Comment: What do you mean by "identify"?

Answer (score 2):

`-net nic[,model=<adapter_model>][,macaddr=<mac>][...]`
This is the actual code, no IP address can be specified here. a VM is actually a standalone machine, which behaves like a physical host. 
If you absolutely need to specify IPs per VM, you can specify the MAC, and set up your DHCP to assign the right IP to the assigned MAC